# What is wrong with this question?

Tags: support, low-quality

It is giving me "It does not meet our quality standards." for

> How do I link my existing account in a website to Openid account, like google account?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some questions you might want to ask yourself.

- Are you sure a reader will know *exactly* what you want when they read this one sentence?
- What is "my existing account in a website"? Which website are you talking about? How are readers supposed to know what account you mean? Your Facebook account? Your reddit account? Your Amazon account?
- Are you certain that your question is on topic for Super User? What computer software problem are you attempting to solve? If your question is about web applications, it is most surely off topic here.
- What have you tried or found out yet? Have you done any research?

Comment: It is related to web application, but super user has a tag for Openid. Is Stack overflow the right place to ask this? Thanks Kiran

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [webapps.SE] for all things related to Google as an OpenID provider, however please add more details to your questions as to what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @Kiranshell Just because there's a tag doesn't mean all questions tagged with it are automatically on-topic. The suitability of a question for a particular StackExchange site is determined by the criteria laid out in the FAQ, not the presence of any tags.